# How to display output in rows of five numbers?

Tags: c++, loops, vector, counter, primes

I'm new to programming and I have to display all the prime numbers that are the product of this code in rows of five. After too many hours of trying to find something online, this is what I came up with. This way, not even the prime numbers are being displayed in the end; only 1s all the way. I'd be happy to know what I did wrong or what I could change.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n { 0 };
    cout << "Please enter an initial value n<2000 in order for the calculation to begin: " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    vector<bool> cygnus(n + 1);               
    for (int m = 0; m <= n; m++) {
        cygnus[m]=true;
    }

    for (int j = 2; j < n; j++) {
        if (cygnus[j] == true) {
            for (int i = j + 1; i <= n; i++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    cygnus[i] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    int s = 0;
    for (auto value : cygnus) {
        if (value == true && s > 0) {
            for (int counter = s; counter++; ) {
                if (counter % 5 == 0) {
                    cout << setw(3) << s << "  \n ";
                }
                
                if (counter % 5 != 0) {
                    cout << setw(3) << s << "  ";
                }
            }
        }

        s++;
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A side note: `m<n` and not `m<=n` in the "for" test, Same for `i<=n` Or else you are trying to access an out-of-range index in the array.

Comment: The best thing for your case is using a debugger to inspect values as the app runs. If you don't use a debugger, put a lot of "cout" with the values you want to inspect everywhere, so as to see what's going on.

Comment: @Ripi2 Actually, I just noticed: The vector is initialized with `n + 1` elements, so the `m<=n` is OK. I made the same mistake in my answer, which I am about to correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seriously over-complicating your output logic. Just have a `counter` variable declared (and initialized to zero) outside the `for` loop that does the output and then, every time you print a number, increment it. When that reaches the value of 5, print a newline and reset it to zero.

A couple of other points:

1. The STL containers (like `std::vector`) use [the `size_t` type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) (not `int`) for their sizes and indexes. In the code below, I have changed all your `int` variables to this type; fortunately, that won't affect your algorithm.
2. Note [that 1 is not a prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number).

Here's a re-worked version of your code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    size_t n{ 0 };
    cout << "Please enter an initial value n<2000 in order for the calculation to begin: " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    vector<bool>cygnus(n + 1);
    for (size_t m = 0; m <= n; m++) {
        cygnus[m] = true;
    }

    for (size_t j = 2; j < n; j++) {
        if (cygnus[j] == true) {
            for (size_t i = j + 1; i <= n; i++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    cygnus[i] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    size_t s = 0;
    size_t counter = 0;
    for (auto value : cygnus) {
        if (value == true && s > 1) { // Note that 1 is NOT a prime number
            cout << setw(3) << s << "  ";
            if (++counter == 5) {
                cout << "\n ";
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
        s++;
    }
    if (counter != 0) cout << "\n "; // Add newline for any partial last line.
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```